# How to import/view Facebook feed in diaspora*?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, diaspora

I am new to [diaspora*](https://diasporafoundation.org/), and my long-term goal is to dump Facebook. I have looked through the options on my pod (https://pod.geraspora.de/i/b24ae58b25be) and in various help files and wikis, but I cannot find a method for viewing Facebook posts from diaspora*.

I have found the options to post something that I write on diaspora* to Facebook (and/or Twitter, Tumbler, and/or WordPress.com). That function is useful, but it is not sufficient for helping to convince my friends to migrate from Facebook to diaspora*.

A news article says that it is possible to view Facebook feeds:

> Their solution was to make Diaspora* play well with others. Sign up
>   for a Diaspora* account, and your posts can easily be imported into
>   Tumblr, Twitter, and even Facebook. In the early stages of its use,
>   Diaspora* can function as a social aggregator, bringing together feeds
>   from various other platforms. The idea is that this lowers the
>   barriers to joining the network, and as more of your friends join, you
>   no longer need to bounce communications through Facebook.

*[The Village Voice](http://www.villagevoice.com/2012-02-15/news/the-facebook-killers/3/)*

Not that Wikipedia is the voice of god, but [it makes the same claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_(software)#Concept), citing the above source.

1. Is it possible to view Facebook feeds in diaspora*?
2. Do I need to install a plug-in?
3. Do I need to be on a different pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diaspora will need `read_stream` permission as a third party application which they will not be approved,

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

So, no, it is not possible to view Facebook feeds in diaspora and there are no workarounds. When Diaspora initially started this might have been possible.